# C++ CLR Dependency in runtime

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, dependencies, runtime, clr

I developed application using C++\CLR to unit managed (C#) and unmanaged (Visual C++) projects. Now on my PC it works well, but on PC without Visual Studio it cant load this DLL (of C++\CLR project). But if I install Visual Studio it works.

So I ask you help me understand what dependency I need install to clean PC.
Of course .Net Framework installed.

In my project I use next includes:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vcclr.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace System;
using namespace std;
```

Platform tools Visual Studio 2013.

stdafx.h is empty.

I think that I need also windows platform SDK. But I am not sure.
I tried to search but not found answer. Help please if you can.

Comment: You always at least have a dependency on the C runtime library, msvcr120.dll.  Stored in c:\windows\syswow64 on your machine, not likely on the other.  Just copy it in the same directory as the .exe file.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor if that still didn't resolve the issue, the trace shows you it searching for the DLL and not finding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers.
Finaly I added to my deploy package dependencies:

- vcredist_2013_runtime_x64
- vcredist_2013_runtime_x86

From Microsoft official website

And it works well =)

Comment: Update for current files:  https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Answer (score 1):

As @Hans Passant mentioned in the comments, this happens because
you have a dependency on C runtime library. You can use the method Hans
suggested and copy the dll of runtime library, or you can change the runtime
library that you are linking to (which will allow you to run you code on a
different machine without the need to copy `msvcr120.dll`). To do this,
open the property pages of your VS project, go to "C/C++" -> "Code Generation"
and modify the value of "Runtime Library" to:

1. "Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)" for "Debug" configuration
2. "Multi-threaded (/MT)" for "Release" configuration

Comment: That's not possible, /clr *requires* /md.  Just try it yourself before you post, takes only a minute.